# SQL CASE checking for two conditions from the same column inside stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server

SQL CASE checking for two conditions from the same column stored procedure sql server not working.

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE CASE WHEN ISNULL(column1,0)=0 THEN ISNULL(OfficeFlg,0)=1 ELSE ISNULL(column2,0)=1 END
```

Comment: _not working._ is far too broad to describe your problem here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for

```
WHERE (column1 IS NULL AND OfficeFlg IS NOT NULL)
      OR
      (column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Let's see your case and try to understand from it what you need

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(column1,0)=0 THEN ISNULL(OfficeFlg,0)=1 ELSE ISNULL(column2,0=1) END
```

- `WHEN ISNULL(column1,0)=0 THEN ISNULL(OfficeFlg,0)=1` mean `column1 IS NULL AND OfficeFlg IS NOT NULL`.
- `ELSE ISNULL(column2,0=1)` mean `column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL`.

Or maybe (cause it's not clear what are you trying to do exactly)

```
WHERE (column1 IS NULL AND OfficeFlg =1 )
      OR
      (column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 =1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use a `CASE` expression like a `CASE` statement; that's not how they work.

`CASE` expressions return a Scalar value, not the result of a boolean expression. If I under your  logic correctly, what you're after in Boolean Logic would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE ((Column1 = 0 OR Column1 IS NULL)
  AND  OfficFlg = 1)
   OR (Column1 != 0 AND Column2 = 1);
```

Notice I've removed the use of `ISNULL` and the `CASE`. Using either in your `WHERE` makes the query non-SARGable, which means performance could be severely effected. For things like `ISNULL` instead, use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` expressions and for `CASE` use boolean logic with `OR`s and `AND`s.

Comment: You're right, @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ . Obviously not enough coffee yet.